# Separar por categoria o formulário de cadastro

Tags: javascript, css, html5

[image: Imagem de exemplo]

Tenho um formulário e gostaria de separar por categorias igual consta de exemplo na imagem, que no caso tem "Dados de Login" e "Dados de Contato"

Como é que faz isso?

Obrigado

Comment: Sua pergunta é ampla de mais, existem mil maneiras de chegar nesse layout. Vc tem que pelo menos colocar o código do que vc já tem pronto de HTML/CSS para podermos te ajudar. Da forma como vc pergunto não tem como te responder

Answer (score 0):

Envolva os campos que você quer separar, com a tag `<fieldset></fieldset>`.
Para colocar uma legenda como no exemplo acima use `<legend>Dados de Login</legend>` que deverá estar dentro da tag `<fieldset>`:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Dados de Login</legend>
    <!-- Conteúdo do campo -->
</fildset>
```

Comment: Mas isso não responde a pergunta... Ele quer que fique igual a imagem!

Comment: Vai muito css então!